# Создать документ word в новом или в уже запущенном процессе winword.exe

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в c# winforms vs2010 исправить код ниже, чтобы новый документ word (oDoc) создавался корректно, т.е. если приложение word еще не запущено, то создать новый word, иначе если уже запущено, то создать новый документ в уже запущенном приложении word? Сейчас при каждом создании документа word создается еще один процесс winword.exe.

```
        Word._Application oWord = new Word.Application();

        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";

        object oTemplate = @"c:\a3.dot";

        oWord.Visible = true;
        oWord.Application.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
        Word._Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        oDoc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WorkTime_v5
{
    public class WordInstanceSingleton
    {
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application m_wordInstance;

        private WordInstanceSingleton() { }

        public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_wordInstance == null)
                {
                    m_wordInstance = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                }
                return m_wordInstance;
            }
        }
    }
}



private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = WordInstanceSingleton.Instance;
object oTemplate = @"c:\a3.dot";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc;
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";

            try
            {
                oWord.Visible = true;
                doc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!");
                return;
            }

            oWord.Application.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
            doc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;


 //...
            doc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;

            doc.Activate();
            oWord.Activate();
```

Comment: Код выше работает, но если при запущенной программе закрыть все созданные окна word (чтобы создать новые), то MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!"). Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить код выше.